# (Qt/C++) Multiple Values in int Array

Tags: c++, arrays, list, int

I am working on a project and it would be much easier if I could fill an int array with more than one int value.

For example:

```
int array[5];

array[0] == 10, 20, 30;
array[1] == 44, 55, 66;
...
```

It's kinda hard for me to explain, but how could I fill an array with multiple int values? Thanks for your time :)

Comment: First of all `==` is equality not assignment(`=`), second can you provide a little more context.

Comment: It was simply my way of expressing what I was looking for. I have an array (slotId[40]) and for my project, each slot has 3 values. I'm wondering how to make on array hold 3 int's per sector.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a multidimensional array:

```
int array[5][3];
array[0][0] = 10; array[0][1] = 20; array[0][2] = 30;
array[1][0] = 44; array[1][1] = 55; array[2][2] = 66;
...
```

or create an array of an ad-hoc struct:

```
struct tuple_3int
{
    int x, y, z;
    tuple_3int() {} 
    tuple_3int(int X, int Y, int Z) : x(X), y(Y), z(Z) {}
};

tuple_3int array[5];
array[0] = tuple_3int(10, 20, 30);
array[1] = tuple_3int(44, 55, 66);
```

Or, if you are using C++11, you can use the new tuples, and declare an array of tuples of 3 ints:

```
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<int, int, int> array[5];
array[0]=std::make_tuple(10, 20, 30);
array[1]=std::make_tuple(44, 55, 66);
```

Comment: That struct looks like what I need. Let me mess with it and I'll get back to you :)

Comment: I'm getting a bunch of errors. I'm sure it's not your code, rather it's me not understanding how to implement this with my current program. The example I provided wasn't a real example. Let's just say I though it would be simpler :/

Comment: You might also want to explain the usage of `std::get` in the C++11 example.

Comment: @mc360pro The struct example looks like it requires a default constructor the way it is setup, I will add a similar example to my answer.

Comment: @mc360pro: Sorry, it needed a default constructor. Now it should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can achive your goal at diffrent ways:

1. Create a triple class of int's, and create array of this class.

i.e.

```
class triple {
int x;
int y;
int z;
public:
triple (int _x, int _y, int _z) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {}
};
```

triple array[SIZE];
array[0] = triple (1,2,3);

1. Enter the values of the int ordinary and refer for every 3 sequential cells as 1 index.

i.e.

```
array[0] = 10;    
array[1] = 44;   
array[2] = 20;   
array[3] = 55;   
array[4] = 30;   
array[5] = 66;
```

Than 0-2 indexes will be your first cell, 3-5 the seconde and so on.

1. Creat a 2D array.

i.e.

```
int array [SIZE][3];
array [i][0] = 1;
array [i][1] = 2;
array [i][2] = 3;
```

Comment: I'm attempting your first suggestion as that is what I need. In my program, I send the array to a function where the values are changed (they're initialized outside the function). But I keep getting errors about syntax "triple" and now "slotId."

Comment: I can't tell you what is it without to see the code. However notice that if you need access to the (x,y,z) fileds you need to: 1) make them public fileds 2) create a get and\or set methods 3) define the class as a struct.

Comment: I suppose I'm too basic with C++, especially in this Qt gui I'm making. I'll mess around and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use 2D array ?!
if number of elements to be saved won't be equal in every cell you can use array of vector or array of list

for example

```
vector<int> array[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use C++11, then a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) seems to be a simple approach, here is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::tuple<int,int,int>> tupleVector ;

    tupleVector.push_back( std::make_tuple( 10, 20, 30 ) ) ;
    tupleVector.push_back( std::make_tuple( 44, 55, 66 ) ) ;

    std::cout << std::get<0>( tupleVector[0] ) << ":" << std::get<1>( tupleVector[0] )  << ":" << std::get<2>( tupleVector[0] )  << std::endl ;
    std::cout << std::get<0>( tupleVector[1] ) << ":" << std::get<1>( tupleVector[1] )  << ":" << std::get<2>( tupleVector[1] )  << std::endl ;
}
```

A non C++11 example could use a `struct` to hold the slot data, you could stick with arrays but `std::vector` is simpler and will cause you less headaches in the long run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

struct slot
{
    int x1, x2, x3 ;

    slot() : x1(0), x2(0), x3() {}   // Note, need default ctor for array example
    slot( int p1, int p2, int p3 ) : x1(p1), x2(p2), x3(p3) {}  
} ;

int main()
{
    std::vector<slot> slotVector ;

    slotVector.push_back( slot( 10, 20, 30 ) ) ;
    slotVector.push_back( slot( 44, 55, 66 ) ) ;

    std::cout << slotVector[0].x1 << ":" << slotVector[0].x2 << ":" << slotVector[0].x3 << std::endl ;

    slot slotArray[5] ;

    slotArray[0] = slot( 10, 20, 30 ) ;
    slotArray[0] = slot( 44, 55, 66 ) ;

    std::cout << slotArray[0].x1 << ":" << slotArray[0].x2 << ":" << slotArray[0].x3 << std::endl ;
}
```

Comment: @mc360pro As far as I understand as long as your relatively recent in your version you should be good.